# Setting resolution for a window using Pyglet and moving

Tags: python, class, pyglet

I'm new to using Pyglet in python and have some problems with my code. First of all, I don't know why setting the resolution doesn't work. Second of all, when I try to move the "snake" it doesn't do anything. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pyglet
import random

pyglet.resource.path = ["resources"]
pyglet.resource.reindex()


class Snake_Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Snake_Window, self).__init__()

        self.width = 1280
        self.height = 720
        # sets the resolution of window

        self.key_handler = pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler()
        self.push_handlers(self.key_handler)
        # sets keys

        self.set_caption("Wild Snake")
        # gives it a name

        self.background_image = pyglet.resource.image("background.png")
        self.food_image = pyglet.resource.image("food.png")
        self.snake_head_image = pyglet.resource.image("snake_head.png")
        self.snake_body_image = pyglet.resource.image("snake_body.png")
        # makes images usable

        self.center_image(self.food_image)
        self.center_image(self.snake_head_image)
        self.center_image(self.snake_body_image)
        # centers the images using center_image

        self.snake_head = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=self.snake_head_image, x=200, y=200)
        self.snake_head.scale = 0.5
        self.snake_head.rotation = 180

        self.snake_body = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=self.snake_body_image, x=400, y=200)
        self.snake_body.scale = 0.5
        self.snake_body.rotation = 180

        self.snake_head.draw()
        self.snake_body.draw()

        self.food = []

        self.c = self.snake_head.x
        self.a = self.snake_head.x
        self.b = self.snake_head.y

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.game_tick, 1)

    def center_image(self, image):
        # sets the center of the image to the actual center
        image.anchor_x = image.width / 2
        image.anchor_y = image.height / 2

    def update_snake_head(self):
        if self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.RIGHT]:
            self.c = self.a
            self.c += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.LEFT]:
            self.c = self.a
            self.c -= 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.UP]:
            self.c = self.b
            self.c += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.DOWN]:
            self.c = self.b
            self.c -= 200
        else:
            print("čau")

    def update_snake_body(self):
        if self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.RIGHT]:
            self.c = self.a
            self.c += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.LEFT]:
            self.c = self.a
            self.c -= 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.UP]:
            self.c = self.b
            self.c += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.DOWN]:
            self.c = self.b
            self.c -= 200
        else:
            print("čau")

    def game_tick(self, dt):
        self.update_snake_head()
        self.update_snake_body()
        self.draw_elements()

    def draw_elements(self):
        self.clear()
        self.snake_head.draw()
        self.snake_body.draw()

game_window = Snake_Window()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. You should ask questions to a specific problem or a specific error message instead of "Why is this code not working?".

Comment: Because the height and width are defined as this: `super(Snake_Window, self).__init__(width=800, height=600)` and not defined after the window is created (the __init__ creates the window)

Comment: The second problem being you updating `self.c` and not `self.snake_head.x`. Those values are not bound to each other. I'm assuming you thought you created a "shortcut" for the different elements - but you didn't. You've created copies of the integer representing the position of the snake upon start. But you're not actually updating the snake, you're updating the copy :)

Comment: Thanks, guys the resolution is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyglet
import random

pyglet.resource.path = ["resources"]
pyglet.resource.reindex()

class Snake_Window(pyglet.window.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Snake_Window, self).__init__(width=1280, height=720)

        # sets the resolution of window

        self.key_handler = pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler()
        self.push_handlers(self.key_handler)
        # sets keys

        self.set_caption("Wild Snake")
        # gives it a name

        self.background_image = pyglet.resource.image("background.png")
        self.food_image = pyglet.resource.image("food.png")
        self.snake_head_image = pyglet.resource.image("snake_head.png")
        self.snake_body_image = pyglet.resource.image("snake_body.png")

        # makes images usable

        self.center_image(self.food_image)
        self.center_image(self.snake_head_image)
        self.center_image(self.snake_body_image)
        # centers the images using center_image

        self.snake_head = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=self.snake_head_image, x=200, y=200)
        self.snake_head.scale = 0.5
        self.snake_head.rotation = 180

        self.snake_body = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img=self.snake_body_image, x=400, y=200)
        self.snake_body.scale = 0.5
        self.snake_body.rotation = 180

        self.snake_head.draw()
        self.snake_body.draw()

        self.food = []

        self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.x
        self.snake_head.y = self.snake_head.y

        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.game_tick, 1)

    def center_image(self, image):
        # sets the center of the image to the actual center
        image.anchor_x = image.width / 2
        image.anchor_y = image.height / 2

    def update_snake_head(self):
        if self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.RIGHT]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.x
            self.snake_head.x += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.LEFT]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.x
            self.snake_head.x -= 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.UP]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.y
            self.snake_head.x += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.DOWN]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.y
            self.snake_head.x -= 200
        else:
            print("čau")

    def update_snake_body(self):
        if self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.RIGHT]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.x
            self.snake_head.x += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.LEFT]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.x
            self.snake_head.x -= 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.UP]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.y
            self.snake_head.x += 200
        elif self.key_handler[pyglet.window.key.DOWN]:
            self.snake_head.x = self.snake_head.y
            self.snake_head.x -= 200
        else:
            print("čau")

    def game_tick(self, dt):
        self.update_snake_head()
        self.update_snake_body()
        self.draw_elements()

    def draw_elements(self):
        self.clear()
        self.snake_head.draw()
        self.snake_body.draw()

game_window = Snake_Window()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Here's how you can get both issues working.
The first issue is that the width and height are defined upon creating the window (there's probably some way of changing it afterwards as well that I haven't bothered learning yet).

The second issue is that you update `self.c` for instance, a copy of `self.snake_head.x`. So when you think you're updating `.x` of `self.snake_head` you're actually updating the copy and nothing more.

The above code works around this. It's not perfect tho, for instance - the key-presses won't trigger/update until the given interval. But these are things you're probably working on after this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out in the end but still have some problems. If you would be so kind and look here about other issues I have.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264615/having-problem-with-the-movement-of-a-snakes-body-in-pyglet